# Can members login and then search membership database?

Tags: civimember

I'm assuming this is the case, but I wanted to confirm. Would members of my organization have the capability of logging in to our membership database and viewing other members information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few different ways to accomplish this.  One tutorial for a members-only directory is available on the CiviCRM wiki: [Creating a website member directory](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Creating+a+website+member+directory)

If you are on Drupal, you could also use Views to create something similar.